# Bad image format exception in 64bit application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, setup-deployment

I have create an application in **32 bit** it works fine but when i change its architecture **from 32 bit to 64 bit** from visual studio its shown an error like **Bad image format exception**.

Application referenced dll `like

> 1. DataAccess 32 bit dll.
> 2. ApplicationData 32 bit dll.
> 3. System dll,
> 4. System.core dll,
> 5. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Getting Error `like :-

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'DataAccess,
>   Version=4.0.0.13, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

Comment: You can't reference a 32bit dll in a 64bit application

Comment: If you want to run in 64bit, you need a 64bit version of DataAccess

Comment: why we can't reference 32 bit dll in 64 bit application?